# Android Studio Shortcut For Showing Linter Hint?

Tags: android, android-studio

When the Android Studio linter warns you about an error (either highlighting it in yellow or underlining in red) you can read about the error by hovering your mouse over the highlight. You can then expand the explanation with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (on a Mac). Is there a shortcut like <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but for making the linter hint show up in the first place? I'd really like to avoid having one hand jump to the mouse (and hover there for a second, waiting) and jump back every time Android Studio wants to say something.

[image: Hint]

Answer (score 1):

You can see warning message in the [Status bar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/status-bar.html) of Android Studio. See below

[image]

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turns out <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> makes the smaller version of the hint pop up, as well. I guess I should've tried that first.